# Linked List in a Array

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am currently doing a online Java course and am having a bit of trouble with a assignment. The assignment is to essentially create a Hashmap using just Arrays but no other Java Data Structures or methods. This is my code:

```java
public class test {

    static String[] array = new String[10];

    class Cell<T> {
        T first;
        Cell<T> next;

        Cell(T h, Cell<T> t) {
            first = h;
            next = t;
        }
    }

    public static int hashFunction(String a) {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char b = a.charAt(i);
            int value = (int) b;
            sum *= value;
        }
        return sum % array.length;
    }

    public static void arraySetter(String a) {
        int position = hashFunction(a);
        if (array[position] == null) {
            array[position] = a;

        } else {
            //Need a Linked List here for when there is already a item in the array at the same index.
        }
    }

    public static void printArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arraySetter("abc");
        printArray();
    }
}
```

My code essentially creates a list of lists. At each position in the Array I now need to create a list which is only initialised when there are two items with the same value for the hashFunction. I haven't written that function yet but my problem now is I don't know how to create a linkedList at each position in the array. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Easier to use dynamic array (since you are apparently not allowed to use ArrayList) than a linked list. IOW, use array, store used size, and at insert create new bigger array and copy, when used size exceeds array total size.

Comment: You don't want an array of strings. You want an array of Cell<String>. But that is not a HashMap at all. A Map is dictionary: it contains values associated with unique keys.

Comment: @JBNizet How is it not a hashmap?

Comment: @shmosel it doesn't have keys and values. It doesn't check for equality of keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is the data structure in which you should store your data:

> Cell[] array

When using an array such as `String[]` you will never be able to add any else than instances of `String` into that array.

When you get a new hashCode, you should create a new one:

> array[position] = new Cell<>(a, null);

As it is the first element from the linkedList we will call it the `head`.

Every time a value with the same hashcode is provided, you will need to iterate from the `head` until a `Cell` whose `next` value is null, then you define it with a new instance of Cell.

This is generally called `addLast` method, and you ca find a good example here:[image: addLast method for linkedList]

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a linked list to avoid collision then you have to declare array which will contain head of the linked list.

```
Node<K,V>[] table;
```

Sample code not fully implemented.

```
class Node<K,V>  {
        K key;
        V value;
        Node<K,V> next;
        }
```

Node will contain current key and value .if key is same then you have to override and also next value if you want to use linked list.If you want to use array to avoid collision that time also use node which will contain key and value key is required to check equality and no next variable.